# Типизация компонента react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Создаю компонент Text в него вложен другой компонент Tag. Как я могу его типизировать, что бы заработало? Сейчас появляется ошибка и он не принимает нужные стили. Ошибка такая:

Type '{ children: ReactNode; classNames: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

Код:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import styles from './Text.module.css';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

interface ITextProps {
    variant: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6' | 'p1' | 'p2' | 'p3';
    bold?: boolean;
}

const tags = {
    h1: 'h1',
    h2: 'h2',
    h3: 'h3',
    h4: 'h4',
    h5: 'h5',
    h6: 'h6',
    p1: 'p',
    p2: 'p',
    p3: 'p',
};

const Text: React.FC<ITextProps> = ({ children, variant, bold }) => {
    const Tag = tags[variant];

    return <Tag classNames={cx({ title: variant === 'h1' })}>{children}</Tag>;
};

export default Text;
```

Comment: по идее в Tag должна быть функция/компонент, а не строка

Comment: тоесть возвращаться должна функция со своими пропсами? не очень понятно всё равно

Comment: нет, чтобы написать `<Tag` - в Tag должна быть функция

Comment: [Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

```
React.FC<ITextProps> // означает что props строго соответствуют ITextProps
```

а на самом деле: в ITextProps отсутствует children, о чем и сообщает компилятор
(добавьте children в ITextProps)